# Is this really how I have to position something on the right in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Inside of a `Column`, with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`, I want to position a child to float right.

This is my solution:

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    [...]
    Container(
      height: 20.0,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Text(
                    "Price - " + _event.price,
                     style: Styles.constratingTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Is there a neater way of doing this? This feels to heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Flutter - Align Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2E7yl3MwMk)

Also you can use `alignment` property of `Container`

Answer (score 1):

```
 SizedBox.expand(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("hello")
        ],
      ),
    )
```

use crossAxisAlignment.end 
   and expand the width taken by column children by wrap column in
    "SizedBox.expand" widget

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with the other suggested solution because it saves creating a new column. My parent column requires the `.start` `crossAxisAligment`. If I were to place multiple things down the right, this may be my go-to. Thanks!

Comment: @louisdeb , most welcome buddy ... happy coding.. :)